# How to access toolbar from a extjs splitbutton menu?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a toolbar like this

```
  tbar: [{
            xtype        : 'textfield',
            name        : 'number',
            itemId        : 'number',
            listeners    : {
                change    : function(t,n){
                        console.log(this.up('toolbar').down('#splitbut')) // i can access splitbutton from here
                }
            }                                                          
        },{
            xtype    : 'splitbutton',
            text    : 'Report',
            disabled: true,
            itemId    : 'splitbut',
            menu    : [{
                    text    : 'details',
                    handler    : function() {
                        // how to access #number text field  from here
                    }
                }
```

i tried like this.up('menu').up('toolbar') inside menu button handler but im getting undefined message for each way i try

any idea how to access #number text field from menu button?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gihan your menu item does not extend from a component that has up function. Try passing in scope to handler function:

```
handler: function() {
            console.log(this.myTextField ) 
        },
scope: this or this.mySplitButton
```

set the break point inside the function and inspect it in firebug. you will clearly see what 'this' refers to at that point. Also if you are going to be developing in ExtJS I would strongly recommend you getting Illuminations fro developers for Firefox - you will love it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, tried pass scope: this with my code and it seems this reference to the main window.

Comment: Gihan, that depends on how and where the config for the entire form is defined. If you move it into initComponent then 'this' will reference the instance of the widget you are defining.

Comment: yeah, i got that after i comment.. Thanks a lot for the suggestion and answer. really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I would define the textfield and the splitbutton separately, then reference them that way.

```
this.myTextField = new Ext.form.field.Text ({
    name: 'number',
    itemId: 'number',
    listeners: {
        change: function(t,n){
            console.log(this.mySplitButton) 
        }
    }    
this.mySplitButton= new Ext.button.Split ({
    text: 'Report',
    disabled: true,
    itemId: 'splitbut',
    menu: [{
        text: 'details',
        handler: function() {
            console.log(this.myTextField ) 
        }
    }
```